# The request or reply is too large

Tags: squid

Some of my visitors get error while loading page:

```
The following error was encountered:

• The request or reply is too large. If you are making a POST or PUT request, then
  your request body (the thing you are trying to upload) is too large. If you are
  making a GET request, then the reply body (what you are trying to download) is
  too large. These limits have been established by the Internet Service Provider
  who operates this cache. Please contact them directly if you feel this is an
  error.

Your cache administrator is webmaster.
```

I read on the internet,that I cant do anything.. But I want to.

What can be a problem? Can I do something with it? Thank you

Comment: Are upload_max_filesize and post_max_size ok? Can you access php.ini?

Comment: What means 'ok' ? :) yes, I can access everything.

Comment: Well, not sure what you're uploading there, so  ok = covers all possibilities :)

Comment: Nothing uploading. Just get request.. (gonna try that squid cache)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message you describe originates from the [Squid Cache](http://www.squid-cache.org/).

Either you are running a misconfigured Squid cache on your web server, or the users who experience this problem are connecting through a misconfigured Squid cache.

Either way, the problem does not lie with your CodeIgniter application.

Comment: Your visitors may be connecting through a proxy server that has Squid installed. This is common in workplace environments.

Comment: Understand what a PROXY SERVER is: (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server). The proxy server is BETWEEN your web server, and the user's browser. If you have no control over the proxy server, then you cannot do anything about your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the problem!

It was the same problem, as I described here (and got minus reputation): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045080/website-for-mobile-white-screen
(I editted the question in this thread to, if somebody finds it throw google)

I've forgotten set_cookie() in my script, which is called very often.
So in HTTP header I had a tons of set_cookie rows. That cache server can't handle it..